# How to prevent CABasicAnimation from scale all content inside UIView?

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I've wrote this to apply heart beat animation to CAShapeLayer, after this worked fine, I need to implement it to be behind UIButton (btnTest) without scaling the UIButton or any other content.

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnTest: UIButton!

let btnLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    btnTest.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: btnTest.frame.midX, y: btnTest.frame.midY), radius: 100, startAngle: 0*(CGFloat.pi / 180), endAngle: 360*(CGFloat.pi / 180), clockwise: true)

    btnLayer.path = ovalPath.cgPath
    btnLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    btnLayer.contentsGravity = "center"
    btnLayer.opacity = 0.3
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(btnLayer)

    let theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
    theAnimation.duration       = 0.75
    theAnimation.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
    theAnimation.autoreverses   = true
    theAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
    theAnimation.toValue        = 1.2
    theAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
    self.view.layer.add(theAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

the is this result [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/26n6MDX4DB9SONKzS/giphy.gif)

another solution was changing this line :

```
self.view.layer.add(theAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

to this :

```
btnLayer.add(theAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

the result of this was this :[gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/l41JRN1ic22TawtOM/giphy.gif)

Any ideas to solve this problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to animate your `btnLayer`. The reason it's animating from the wrong place is probably that the layer's `anchorPoint` is at 0,0, where it should be set to 0.5, 0.5.

### Edit:

Actually, I think the issue is where you put your `btnLayer`. You should make it a sublayer of your button view's layer, and give it a frame that's the bounds of the button's layer:

```
btnTest.layer.addSublayer(btnLayer)
btnLayer.frame = btnTest.layer.bounds
```

Comment: I've added your suggested answer with/without anchor point, the CAShaper layer moved to the right bottom corner. :(

Comment: But you approved my answer? Rather than editing my answer, can you post your own answer that shows the code that worked?

Comment: Your answer was the key to make this work, the first line as is yours , the second is just to give it a defined rect ! I think it's not kind to take your answer and makes it belongs to me ! You have the right to get an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, just translate your layer alongside with scale animation. To do so you need to create a CAAnimationGroup.

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    btnTest.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: btnTest.frame.midX, y: btnTest.frame.midY), radius: 100, startAngle: 0*(CGFloat.pi / 180), endAngle: 360*(CGFloat.pi / 180), clockwise: true)

    btnLayer.path = ovalPath.cgPath
    btnLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    btnLayer.anchorPoint = CGPoint.init(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    btnLayer.contentsGravity = "center"
    btnLayer.opacity = 0.3
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(btnLayer)

    let theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.xy")
    theAnimation.fromValue      = 1.0
    theAnimation.toValue        = 1.2

    let theAnimationTranslationX = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    theAnimationTranslationX.fromValue      = btnTest.bounds.minX
    theAnimationTranslationX.toValue        = btnTest.bounds.minX - 40

    let theAnimationTranslationY = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.y")
    theAnimationTranslationY.fromValue      = btnTest.bounds.minY
    theAnimationTranslationY.toValue        = btnTest.bounds.minY - 80


    let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup.init()
    animationGroup.duration       = 0.75
    animationGroup.repeatCount    = Float.infinity
    animationGroup.autoreverses   = true
    animationGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
    animationGroup.animations = [theAnimation,theAnimationTranslationX,theAnimationTranslationY]

    btnLayer.add(animationGroup, forKey: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First make the heart shape that will animate a `UIView` let's name it `heartView`.

2- `self.view.addsubview(heartView)` (`self.view` can be changed to any parent you want)

3- make an invisible button called `heartButton` and give it the same frame of `heartView`

4- `self.view.addsubview(heartButton)` (`self.view` can be changed to any parent you want)

5- start the heartView animation.

The key point here is not to add the button on the animating view but on their parent (`self.view` this case) since if the `button` was on top of the heart and the heart is animating, the button will adopt the animation.

Hope this helps!